# Apparent Multiple Failures Using Google Chrome Versions 30 to 33

Tags: jssor

I've been developing the Image Slider Theme(dated 02/20/2015 - Jssor Slider 18.0 Development Kit)(Jssor.Slider.FullPack\demos-no-jquery\image-slider-2.source.html with jssor.slider.min.js). I have not modified the javascript code. I'm finding failures of various script implementations in Chrome versions 30 through 33 with this Image Slider and several other in the Development Kit. Previous January Development Kit also shows errors. No problems with any other browsers or versions of those browsers that are not already indicated and/or addressed.

I have found that tweaking the function SetPosition "elseif" from:

"            else if ($Jssor$.$IsBrowserChrome() && $Jssor$.$BrowserVersion() >= 30 && $Jssor$.$BrowserVersion() < 34)"

to:

"            else if ($Jssor$.$IsBrowserChrome() && $Jssor$.$BrowserVersion() >= 32 && $Jssor$.$BrowserVersion() < 34)"

```
    function SetPosition(elmt, position) {
        var orientation = _DragOrientation > 0 ? _DragOrientation : _PlayOrientation;
        var x = _StepLengthX * position * (orientation & 1);
        var y = _StepLengthY * position * ((orientation >> 1) & 1);

        if ($Jssor$.$IsBrowserChrome() && $Jssor$.$BrowserVersion() < 38) {
            x = x.toFixed(3);
            y = y.toFixed(3);
        }
        else {
            x = Math.round(x);
            y = Math.round(y);
        }

        if ($Jssor$.$IsBrowserIE() && $Jssor$.$BrowserVersion() >= 10 && $Jssor$.$BrowserVersion() < 11) {
            elmt.style.msTransform = "translate(" + x + "px, " + y + "px)";
        }
        else if ($Jssor$.$IsBrowserChrome() && $Jssor$.$BrowserVersion() >= 30 && $Jssor$.$BrowserVersion() < 34) {
            elmt.style.WebkitTransition = "transform 0s";
            elmt.style.WebkitTransform = "translate3d(" + x + "px, " + y + "px, 0px) perspective(2000px)";
        }
        else {
            $Jssor$.$CssLeft(elmt, x);
            $Jssor$.$CssTop(elmt, y);
        }
    }
```

I'm using this as a quick-fix until I can delve into it further. Has anyone noticed anything along this line?

Comment: Actually, removing the entire "elseif" solves more than one problem. Maybe I better check the browser...

Answer (score 0):

The following code is to improve performance of sliding left<->right for chrome (version 30 to 33).

```
else if ($Jssor$.$IsBrowserChrome() && $Jssor$.$BrowserVersion() >= 30 && $Jssor$.$BrowserVersion() < 34) {
    elmt.style.WebkitTransition = "transform 0s";
    elmt.style.WebkitTransform = "translate3d(" + x + "px, " + y + "px, 0px) perspective(2000px)";
}
```

After about a year, chrome went to version 40. Now it's time to remove it.

Thanks.

Comment: I should have figured that out on the older bowser config. I totally misread it. Thankx for your response, and a great software collection.